# OpenGL single circular wave

Tags: opengl, waveform

I am trying to implement a circular wave in OpenGL using Gerstner wave function:

[image]

It works fine but all my ground is deformed with more waves and all I want is a single wave propagating from the center to the exterior. I tried to modify the z position for the points where `sqrt(x*x + y*y)` is between two circles to limit the boundaries of a wave. The two circles the first circle has the radius of `wavelength * time` and the second has the radius of `wavelength * (time + 1)`, but this still isn't good enough because the circles are expanding slower than the speed of the wave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you calculate the boundaries by `wavelength * time`, you're assuming the wavefront is moving with a speed equal to the wavelength; after 1 unit time, the wavefront will have traveled `wavelength` units in your calculation.

Try using the wave speed that you used to calculate $\varphi$ instead of `wavelength` there.